# C Segmentation Fault structs/pointers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm a little out of experience with my C programming, and I am certain this is something simple that I'm going to kick myself for later, but I can't figure it out.  I don't want to post too much code, but here is what's relevant:

```
#define MAX_COMMAND_ARGS 9
#define MAX_COMMAND_SIZE 80

typedef struct
{
  int   argc;
  char* argv[MAX_COMMAND_ARGS + 1];
  char* history[MAX_COMMAND_SIZE+1];
  size_t size;

} Command;



void History(const Command* cmd)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cmd->size-1; ++i)
    {
      printf("%s\n", cmd->history[i]);
    }
}
```

And this line that exists inside another function as commands are entered:

```
command->history[command->size] = command->argv[0];
++(*command).size;
```

I'm trying to implement a simple history command, but I get a seg fault every time I call the History function.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I fixed the format issue, I'd been messing with the printf line.  This is the line where I get the seg fault:

```
printf("%s\n", cmd->history[i]);
```

Comment: Well, you don't tell us what line is throwing the exception, nor show any of the code that calls History(). You most likely have a null pointer or a buffer overrun. This is why debuggers exist. Lean how to use it. It will be your best friend.  Also, you are attempting to print two strings in your printf, and only have one parameter.  May be the issue.

Comment: compile your software with `-Wall` and read the warnings.

Comment: Are you getting the seg fault on the first iteration?

Comment: Could it be that your `cmd->size` is 0? Your exclusive upper bound of the loop is `cmd->size - 1` compared to a `size_t`, an unsigned quantity, with an unsigned comparison. `i` will then wrap and be interpreted as a 2^32 - 1 or even 2^64 - 1. (Might not be the issue here, but I recommend using `size` as the real size here and store an empty command after that. Should be safe, because you have memory for one more than `MAX_SIZE`.)

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation Fault is generally an attempt to access memory that the CPU cannot physically address.

```
Avoid using uninitialized pointer.
```

Allocate some memory using malloc() or calloc() and assign it to a pointer and then assign values to it.

Answer (score 0):

A very possible hint is that you are not allocating memory for the history table.

Try to insert history entries with `strdup` function, and do not forget to call `free` after removing the entry from the list.

If this is not your problem, you'll need to give us more code.